# Converting an image file to PDFin VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, itext, converters

I need to convert an image file to pdf and save that pdf to the web server. I am using iTextSharp with VB.Net and nothing I have tried will write the pdf created with iTextSharp to disk. Here is the code I am using to create the pdf object.

```
    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = fuCV.FileBytes

    Dim doc As New iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35)
    Dim img As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(fileBytes)
    img.ScaleToFit(280.0F, 260.0F)
    img.SpacingBefore = 30.0F
    img.SpacingAfter = 1.0F
    img.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
    Dim paragraph = New Paragraph()
    doc.Open()
    doc.Add(paragraph)
    doc.Add(img)
```

I've need to save the doc object to disk. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (FileStream ms = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("pdfs" + "/pdf1.pdf"), FileMode.Create))
{
     Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
     PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
     document.Open();
     iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("imagenes") + "/Acceso.jpg");
     document.Add(image);
     document.Close();
     writer.Close();
}
```

I Forgot say, that you need have create two folders, one with pdfs name and other with imagenes name.